# How to change values of repeated array keys to numbers which are incremented

Tags: php, arrays

I need to change values of 'transaction_user_id'to incremented number.
If array has key [transaction_user_id] then 1 should be assighned to it etc. For example if has [transaction_user_id] then [transaction_user_id] = 1, to second one [transaction_user_id] = 2.

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [transaction_user_id] => 359691e27b23f8ef3f8e1c50315cd506
            [transaction_no] => 19500912050218
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [transaction_no] => 36010512050819
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [transaction_user_id] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
            [transaction_no] => 19020512050820
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [transaction_user_id] => 9def02e6337b888d6dbe5617a172c18d
            [transaction_no] => 27050512050821
            [transaction_total_amount] => 79.00
            [transaction_date] => 1336476927
            [transaction_status] => cancelled
        )


)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach this using `array_walk`

```
$i = 1;
array_walk($arr, function(&$v,$k) use (&$i){
  array_key_exists('transaction_user_id', $v) ? ($v['transaction_user_id'] = $i AND $i++) : '';
});
```

Result:-

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [transaction_user_id] => 1
        [transaction_no] => 19500912050218
        [transaction_status] => cancelled
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [transaction_no] => 36010512050819
        [transaction_status] => cancelled
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [transaction_user_id] => 2
        [transaction_no] => 19020512050820
        [transaction_status] => cancelled
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [transaction_user_id] => 3
        [transaction_no] => 27050512050821
        [transaction_total_amount] => 79
        [transaction_date] => 1336476927
        [transaction_status] => cancelled
    )

  )
```

Comment: @Tod you can go through PHP manual and do practice based on different data, you will be expert soon...:)

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways.

this one you have to specify the key path in the original array to change the value
since it wont pass the subarray by reference on default.

```
$increment_id = 1;
foreach($arr as $key=>$transaction) {
    if(isset($transaction['transaction_user_id'])) {
     $arr[$key]['transaction_user_id'] = $increment_id++;   
    }
}
```

in this one, i am passing the subarray as reference, so you can access the value
you want to change directly and will apply to the original array.

```
$increment_id = 1;
foreach($arr as &$transaction) {
    if(isset($transaction['transaction_user_id'])) {
     $transaction['transaction_user_id'] = $increment_id++;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a repeated user id needs to correspond to the same increment number, for example, if array 2 and 3 should both be assigned 2 because they have the same transaction_user_id, you'll have to keep track of that relationship as you go.

Iterate the data, updating an array that maps transaction_user_id to the new increment id as you go. If you find a new one, assign it an incremented value in the array. Then replace the value in your data with the correct increment value.

```
$key = 'transaction_user_id';
$user_ids = [];
$next_id = 1;

foreach ($your_data as $index => $transaction) {
    if (isset($transaction[$key])) {
        if (!isset($user_ids[$transaction[$key]])) {
            $user_ids[$transaction[$key]] = $next_id++;
        }
        $your_data[$index][$key] = $user_ids[$transaction[$key]];
    }
}
```

<sub>(Seems like that's not the case since you already accepted an answer that doesn't do that, but I already wrote it so I'll post it anyway in case it's useful to anyone else who finds this.)</sub>